# Service instantiated twice after APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, singleton, angular6

Problem is: I need to make an http call and store an object that is needed for generate dynamic routes. So, I was taking advantage of the APP_INITIALIZER.

```js
// app.module.ts
import { ApplicationService } from './application.service';


providers: [
  ApplicationService,
  { 
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appServiceFactory, deps: 
  [Injector, ApplicationService], multi: true 
  },
],

function appServiceFactory(injector: Injector, appService: ApplicationService): Function {
  return () => {
    return appService.loadApplication().then((app: Application) => {
      /custom logic
      });
    });
  };
}


// application.service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

// navigation.component.ts
import { ApplicationService } from './application.service';

export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _applicationService: ApplicationService) {
  }
}
```

But inside navigation.component, applicationservice is initialized again. I'm sure of that because if I log or put a debugger statement, the construct() method of the service is called twice.

Why even if the Service is declared as singleton with the `providedIn: root` is being reinstantiated?

Comment: Can you show use how you're importing module?

Comment: @PankajParkar added

Comment: I mean to say how you are importing module inside NgModule's `imports` array. this module is loaded lazily or eagerly?

Comment: @PankajParkar the service is loaded inside the root module. I'm using only 1 module.

Comment: what is `appServiceFactory`, I don't see that function anywhere in the code.

Comment: @PankajParkar added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183370/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-lucgenti).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason for this is that once you include `Router` in dependencies to your `APP_INITIALIZER` factory you get circular dependency (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4c2ce4e8ba4c5ac5ce8754d67bc6603eaad4564a/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L61-L64).

```
ApplicationService
       |
    TestService
       |
     Router
       |
  ApplicationRef
       |
ApplicationInitStatus
       |
 APP_INITIALIZER
       |
ApplicationService
```

To solve this you can get Router lazily:

```
export class TestService {

  get router() {
    return this.injector.get(Router)
  }

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private injector: Injector ) {
  }
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5mzak?file=src/app/test.service.ts)**

Answer (score 2):

Based on your Explanation that you have added the `providedIn: root` in the `application.service.ts` , that means it will be added to the root module (i.e Appmodule.ts) and again in the `Appmodule.ts` in your `provider` array you are adding `ApplicationService`.

From this [Blog](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/05/04/what-is-new-angular-6/) its state that

> "There is now a new, recommended, way to register a provider, directly
>   inside the @Injectable() decorator, using the new providedIn
>   attribute. It accepts 'root' as a value or any module of your
>   application. When you use 'root', your injectable will be registered
>   as a singleton in the application, and you don’t need to add it to the
>   providers of the root module. Similarly, if you use providedIn:
>   UsersModule, the injectable is registered as a provider of the
>   UsersModule without adding it to the providers of the module."

this is creating the service to be reinstantiated

**Edit1 :**
Another thing to check is , 
1. How are you calling this service i mean in Dev mode or Prod mode , if its dev mode then service will be called twice

> If you're running in development mode, it will run the function at
>   least twice. since in development mode it does a check, changes, then
>   rechecks to verify, where production mode only does the first check,
>   assuming you've done your quality assurance and resolved any values
>   the get changed post checking.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/59532r/function_being_called_multiple_times/d95vjlz/)

Try to check in Prod Mode and verify it..

Comment: If I remove the providedIn: root declaration, it still keeps being instantiated twice. Also, I can't remove it from the providers array because it's needed for the appServiceFactory function provided to APP_INITIALIZER

Comment: @lucgenti it would be better if you can keep the code in slackblitz or any other means so that it will help in debugging more. right now we will be giving the solutions on case by case which is of no use

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwyugy but here seems like is getting instantiated just one time

Comment: instead, in my app it keeps doing that even if enableProdMode();

Comment: seems like the problem is not that the service is instantiated twice beacuse of dependency injection in a component. It's during the bootstrap that it's been called twice (1 for the module, 1 for the factory). So the data retrieved from the factory is lost.

Comment: @lucgenti how are? you confirming that data is loaded twice

Comment: No, because loadApplication(), the function responsible for retrieving and storing data, is called only from the factory. And it's correct that is done like so: I should only make 1 http call at application initialization, not 2 calls.

Comment: @lucgenti why are u , using promise ? any reason

Comment: APP_INITIALIZER expects a promise

Answer (score 1):

I also faced an issue that my service was instantiated twice and from what I've seen in logs, one constructor was called from `config.service.ts` file and second from `config.service.js` (note the extension difference). It occurred that by mistake I imported my service like this:

`import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service.js';`

instead of:

`import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';`

Changing it to proper import solved the issue.

Comment: super cool answer :) This was the case for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: it was because of the Router, needed as dependency by a service injected in ApplicationService.

See example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwyugy

When Router is removed from the ApplicationService, the double instantiation is gone.

Can't understand why, so I'll wait for a better answer for approving.

Comment: Had a similar issue, except mine was because I added the parent module to my module so that I could use a component (loaded in the parent module) in my module.   It felt wrong at the time, but was strangely the only way I could add that particular component (tried all the `exports` and `entryComponents` stuff).  Anyway, ended up extracting the component to a "common" module, which I included my module and the resolved the issue like yours.