# Angular APPINITIALIZER TypeError : undefined is not an object and Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to integrate oauth2 refresh token into my app and helps with [this post](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/25/angular-10-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens#app-initializer-ts) but I have an error when loading:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'authenticationService.refreshToken') —
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

app.initializer.ts

```
import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/_services';

export function appInitializer(authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    console.log("Initialize application...");
    return () => new Promise(resolve => {
        // attempt to refresh token on app start up to auto authenticate
        authenticationService.refreshToken()
            .subscribe()
            .add(resolve);
    });
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/_services';

...

providers: [ 
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appInitializer, multi: true, deps: [AuthenticationService] },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```

authentication.service.ts:

```
refreshToken() {
        console.log('Trying to refresh token...');
        return this.http.post(this.apiSettings.auth_url, {
            grant_type: 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token: '',
            client_id: this.apiSettings.client_id,
            client_secret: this.apiSettings.client_secret,
            scope: ''
          }).pipe(map((user) => {
                console.log(user);
                this.userSubject.next(user);
                this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just resolve inside `subscribe` block? Try `authenticationService.refreshToken().subscribe(() => resolve())`

Comment: Hi @CommercialSuicide, thank you for your help but I have the same error with your trick

Comment: Btw, is it a build error, or your app compiles fine and you see this in devtools console when open the page? If it's a build error, it's probably because of typescript and incompatible types.

Comment: It's not a build error, it appears when loading page, compilation is good

Comment: Are you sure that `authenticationService` itself and  `authenticationService.refreshToken` are defined inside your `appInitializer` function? Try to log them and ensure, that both of them exist and `refreshToken` is a function.

Comment: When I try to log `authenticationService`, it appears that my APP_INITIALIZER is called twice, at the first call, `authenticationService` is undefined but in the second time, `authenticationService` is defined and `refreshToken()` is defined

Comment: If so, the simplest way to fix that is to check `authenticationService` for existence and call `authenticationService.refreshToken()` only if `authenticationService` exists itself. For deeper understanding and possible solutions check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226116/service-instantiated-twice-after-app-initializer

Comment: thank you @CommercialSuicide to your help, I try to investigate more

Comment: The problem is in my `AuthenticationService` with `Router` injection, if I uncomment `Router` injection, it works. I'm loading `Router` lazily in my `AuthenticationService` and all is good.